# Empty/Remove Puppet Clientbucket

Tags: ubuntu, puppet

The `/var/lib/puppet/clientbucket` is filling up on one of my servers very quickly and taking up all of the inodes.

Am I safe to run `rm -r '/var/lib/puppet/clientbucket/*';` without any negative effects other than no backup option?

Is there a way to stop Puppet from using clientbucket?

Comment: Related and useful: https://ask.puppetlabs.com/question/132/does-filebucket-need-periodic-maintenance-cleaning/

Comment: Thanks. I did see this post and I run the command supplied frequently (with 10 days threshold). Still fills up too quickly.

Comment: Maybe you could create a cronjob to remove these files every say... one hour? This will you can stop doing it manually and it will happen automatically.

Comment: Why is your filebucket filling up quickly? Only first puppet execution SHOULD change things.

Comment: More servers are added pretty much on a daily basis, is that what could be filling it up? I'm not going to pretend to know a vast amount about Puppet. So can I create a Cron script to clean this folder down completely with no adverse effects?

Answer (score 1):

Please be sure you are not using filebucket and do not need any files restored from filebucket after puppet deployment.

If you really don't need filebucket - yes, you can delete what's inside the folder without being afraid of the consequences. If you aren't using filebucket, and do big deployments, it really can fill up too much.
As long as you don't use filebucket, it's totally safe and won't fail your puppet runs.

Have fun!

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the proper way to ensure that it does not fill up is to set the

```
recurselimit => 1,
```

option of the [file type](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/7/types/file.html).

Comment: That's like saying "The way to avoid spending all your money is to buy smaller things."  It is approximately true that avoiding deeply recursive `File` resources will reduce the space consumption of a server-side filebucket, but that's not a real solution if in fact you need such resources.  It also is not certain to be effective, as filebucketting a few large, non-recursively managed files can be as heavy as filebucketting many small ones.  Overall, `recurselimit` should be used where appropriate, but it is not otherwise a solution to the problem presented.

Comment: @JohnBollinger : since the OP wrote "I'm not going to pretend to know a vast amount about Puppet", it seemed sensible to point him to an alternative to emptying the client bucket by hand . It would be good to know: What alternative makes more sense ?

Comment: This answer does not present an alternative to emptying the client bucket by hand.  It presents a possible measure for preventing it from filling so quickly, but one that in practice is unlikely to be applicable.  Only if the OP were using `recurse=true` to manage files that in fact they did not need or did not want to manage would this be suitable.  Otherwise, either it would not help, or it would break the OP's manifest set.

Comment: Instead of "The way to avoid spending all your money is to buy smaller things", maybe it's akin to "The way to avoid spending all your money is to buy only the things you need." ? It helped to keep the client bucket less full when a colleague did it this way.